# Interactive graphs using java graphics API (2D/3D/OpenGL/etc)?

Tags: java, graph, java-2d, java-3d

Recently searching for a 'technical article' I stumbled upon this Microsoft page: http://academic.research.microsoft.com/. I found the paper I was looking for but was amazed by its **VisualExplorer** feature.

Have a look at this page: http://academic.research.microsoft.com/VisualExplorer#2037349.

The above page uses `SilverLight` and will recommend you to **use IE**.

Like a curious human being I am now thinking of possible ways to implement it. A part of it seems easy:

1. Parse the documents
2. Make a list a authors(V) and distance between them (E) (i.e. co-author or co-co-author)
3. Traverse the above graph (Breadth First)
4. Show the top 5 or 6 connections

I know (or rather feel) this could be easily done in Flash, javascript or silverlight. But is there a way to do this using Java 2D/3D or OpenGL bindings?

Any or every thoughts are welcome.

---

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One option would be [Zest](http://www.eclipse.org/gef/zest/). It supports interaction and animations. Check out some [snippets](http://wiki.eclipse.org/index.php/GEF_Zest_Visualization#Getting_Started) and [stuff](http://wiki.eclipse.org/Zest#Zest_2.x).